# Java Swing - File Architecture/Organization/Optimization

Tags: java, swing, architecture, jbutton, organization

I'm a few weeks into teaching myself Java Swing. I'm writing my own Calculator program from scratch which I eventually want to add a few extra features to.

The majority of the UI is buttons and the structure of my classes has made it so I have a LOT of files. I set it up in a way where I have a ButtonTemplate class which houses all of my basic button information like size, color, font, etc. Then I created a separate class for each of my buttons which extend ButtonTemplate to be added into my ButtonFrame. This means that, right now, I have 18 separate buttons which requires 18 separate classes and seems like it's getting a little out of hand.

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to organize this. Either via classes or folders or some other method that I'm not aware of. As-is, I have a single calculator program that's about half-completed and I already have about 25 files in it.

Comment: How about a `ButtonFactory` with a single `public static JButton createButton(Color color, String text)` method.  In that method, configure the button and return it.  Then your main class can just do `JButton button1 = ButtonFactory.createButton(Color.red, "Add");`. Also, codereview.stackexchange site is probably a better place for these sorts of questions: it's a bit too open-ended for stackoverflow.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice on the question avenue. Since we're here, I ended up creating all of these buttons separately because they all have certain parameters of their own. Specifically, a keymap hotkey. I realized I could probably put these all inside a single class but I'm not sure if that would be wise because that single class controls my layout and I would end up with 200+ lines of code and 20 objects which would make organization and future changes a total nightmare.

Comment: Generally, I organize my Java Swing applications using a [model / view / controller (MVC) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  See my article, [Stock Picker Using Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=709), for an in depth example of the MVC pattern in a Swing application.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your classes into packages, which allow one to "find and use, to avoid naming conflicts, and to control access". See the java tutorials at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html for more information